# How to show numbers in stack to textbox

Tags: c#, textbox, stack, richtextbox

How I can show all the integers in the `Stack<int>` to a `Textbox` or box list or `RichTextbox`?

```
 Stack<int> number = new Stack<int>();

 number.Push(5);
 number.Push(8);
 number.Push(9);
 number.Push(20);
 number.Push(30);
```

here's my code

Comment: `myTextBox.Text = string.Join(", ", number);`

Answer (score 2):

Well, [string.Join](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.join?view=net-6.0) is enough to get text representation (for a `Textbox`, `RichTextbox`):

```
  // 30, 20, 9, 8, 5 
  myTextBox.Text = string.Join(", ", number);
```

Or, if you want to get items in *reversed* order, add `Reverse()` *Linq* method extension:

```
  using System.Linq;

  ...

  // 5, 8, 9, 20, 30
  myTextBox.Text = string.Join(", ", number.Reverse());
```

Note, that `number` is kept *intact*. If you want to put items into a `ListBox` or alike:

```
  foreach (var item in number)
    myListBox.Add(item);
```